# Strange xcode errors using box2d

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, objective-c++

im using xcode4 and box2d/cocos2d.

Im having some strange difficulties with runtime errors that pop up 'randomly'.
I think they occur more when I dont stop the process before rebuilding/running.
Usually if i stop the process before i rebuild/run errors dont occur.

Sometimes I get an:

> 'NSInvalidArguementException', reason
>   '-[ConstructLayer createCog:::]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x554ecd0.

Sometimes I get a strange error in a file called:

> llvm:InstCombiner::DoOneIteration(llvm::Function&,
>   unsigned
>   int)_disassembly_0x026bc64f.nasm

with the line highlighted:

> 0x02bc64f <+0439> mov 0x20(%eax),%ecxn
>
> And sometimes i get an error: malloc *** error for object 0x68d4ba4: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.

Here is my dealloc method:

```
- (void) dealloc{
delete world;
world = NULL;
body_block1 = NULL;
body_egg = NULL;
body_poly = NULL;

[_block1 release];
[_egg release];
[_poly release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

What on earth is happening? Usually errors happen 3 times in a row with different errors before it starts running again.
Help!
Thanks,
Oliver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Make an array nil after releasing it.

```
[_block1 release];
_block = nil;

[_egg release];
_egg = nil;

[_poly release];
_poly = nil;
```